# Remove dollar sign function not working

Tags: php, function, str-replace

I wrote a script to remove R$ from a string this way:

```
$money ="R$ 100,00";
$charactersToBeRemoved = array("R", "$", " ");
$changedValue = str_replace($charactersToBeRemoved, "", $money);
```

This script works fine on the main script, but if I create a function for it like:

```
    function removeDollar($x) {       
       $charactersToBeRemoved = array("R", "$", " "); 
       $changedValue = str_replace($charactersToBeRemoved, "", $x); 
       return $changedValue;    
    }    

   $money = "R$100,00";           
   $newValue = removeDollar($money);
   echo $newValue;
```

`$newValue` still shows R$100,00.

Notes:

This function was created on functions.php file where is already included by include function on the main script.

I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Seems to be working? https://3v4l.org/JiCMT

Comment: *"where is already included by include function on the main script."* - if the file is included somewhere, then you may have a variable scope issue

Answer (score 1):

Works fine like this

```
    function removeDollar($x) {
       $charactersToBeRemoved = array("R", "$", " ");
       $removeTo = array("","","");
       $changedValue = str_replace($charactersToBeRemoved, $removeTo, $x);
       return $changedValue;
    }

   $money = "R$100,00";
   $newValue = removeDollar($money);
   echo $newValue;
   // output 100,00
```

You can check the above code in this [PHP Sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac1ea0915a384473bdbb0c87a6f82bae407bfa00)

and works fine like this (in your example)

```
    function removeDollar($x) {
       $charactersToBeRemoved = array("R", "$", " ");
       $changedValue = str_replace($charactersToBeRemoved, "", $x);
       return $changedValue;
    }

   $money = "R$100,00";
   $newValue = removeDollar($money);
   echo $newValue;
   // output 100,00
```

You can check the above code in this [PHP Sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3028d7db95c5b874d465c26972daba9f0c0814e)

and in case you need to check all string characters

```
    function removeDollar($x) {
    $charArray = str_split($x);
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach($charArray as $char){
     if($char!=="R" && $char!=="$" && $char!==" ") {
        array_push($returnArray,$char);
     }
    }
    $money = implode("",$returnArray);
    return  $money;
    }

   $money = "R$100,00";
   $newValue = removeDollar($money);
   echo $newValue;
```

You can check the above code in this [PHP Sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a367365f75232ac3a3aa7196f443b63159d0c158)

Comment: The first code worked for me. I still don't know what I was doing wrong with my code, buy yours worked! Thanks!

Comment: @FilipeMarques if you check all sandbox links you will see that all code samples work. But since some other way solved your problem then... cheers :)